# Why doesn't specifying predicates and objects work in Fuseki?

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I am trying to load the DBpedia's Ontology Infoxbox properties http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.8/en/mappingbased_properties_en.ttl.bz2, http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#h227-1 into a Fuseki server running on my machine.

For that I did the following

1. Create the tdb using the following command

   java tdb.tdbloader --loc=dbpedia mappingbased_properties_en.ttl
2. Ran the server using the following

   .\fuseki-server.bat --loc=../dbpedia /dbpedia

Trying a simple query like

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?s ?p ?o
where
{?s ?p ?o.}
LIMIT 100
```

works just fine giving results like

```
| dbpedia:Animal_Farm | foaf:name          | "Animal Farm"@en
| dbpedia:Animal_Farm | foaf:name          | "Animal Farm: A Fairy Story"@en
| dbpedia:Animal_Farm | dbpedia-owl:author | dbpedia:George_Orwell
```

The problem happens when I specify the predicate

```
select ?s ?o
where
{?s foaf:name ?o.}
LIMIT 100
```

or the object

```
select ?s ?p
where
{?s ?p dbpedia:George_Orwell.}
LIMIT 100
```

where I get empty results.

Specifying the subject, however, works

```
select ?p ?o
where
{dbpedia:Animal ?p ?o.}
LIMIT 100
```

Any ideas why specifying the predicate or the object doesn't work?

Note: The exact query works just fine on DBpedia. I'm therefore suspecting Fuseki but I'm unable to pinpoint the reason why it's not working

Comment: can you be more specific? - salut! sid

Answer (score 2):

I loaded the data and your queries work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It also works in my machine (ubuntu 14.0, Fuseki v1)